# get source of selected file in ionicframwork

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile app using ionic. One of the usecase is to let the user browse a file and upload it to the backend server (which exposes a rest service).
On the UI, I am using the html file tag.

```html
<input type="file" ng-select="uploadFile($files)" multiple>
```

```js
.controller('UploadDocCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

  $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
   console.log("selected file "+files);
   // hard coded file path "/android_asset/www/img/ionic.pdf" to be replaced with the user selected file
   $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(restServiceEndpoint, "/android_asset/www/img/ionic.pdf", properties).then(function(result) {
   console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
  }, function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
   }, function (progress) {
// constant progress updates
  });
});
```

The problem is that I am not able to get a reference to the selected file. Can someone please help with the steps to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keep file in www folder which has index.html file.

then just give path like "ionic.pdf"

```
.controller('UploadDocCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

  $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
   console.log("selected file "+files);
   // hard coded file path "/android_asset/www/img/ionic.pdf" to be replaced with the user selected file
   $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(restServiceEndpoint, "ionic.pdf", properties).then(function(result) {
   console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
  }, function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
   }, function (progress) {
// constant progress updates
  });
});
```